# 'Could not deduce template argument for 'T'' when trying to parse variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, variadic-templates

I'm trying to pass in a list of struct types into another class, which will take each custom class and add sort of put the struct type into a wrapper and insert that into a tuple. I'm new to templates in general, and can't figure out why the code wont compile.

**The template-parser-wrapper thing**

```
namespace engine
{
    template<class T>
    struct component_manager
    {
        int component_id;

        std::vector<T> components;

        component_manager() : component_id(id_counter) { id_counter++; }
    };

    template<class... Ts>
    class ecs_manager
    {
    public:
        std::tuple<> components;
        
        template<class... Ts>
        ecs_manager()
        {
            constructor_helper<Ts...>();
        }

        template<class T, class... Ts>
        void constructor_helper()
        {
            components = std::tuple_cat(components, component_manager<T>());
            constructor_helper<Ts...>();
        }

        template<class T>
        void constructor_helper() {}
    };
}
```

**The structs**

```
struct transform
{
    engine::vector3 position;
    engine::vector3 rotation;
    engine::vector3 scale;
};

struct motion
{
    engine::vector3 velocity;
};

struct mesh
{
    int id;
};
```

**Creating the template-parser-wrapper-thing**
`engine::ecs_manager<transform, motion, mesh> ecs;`

When compiling, I get these:
Could not deduce template argument for '`T`'
No matching overloaded function found

Comment: Could you please fix the example? By the way, I think you can delete the `constructor_helper` struct and simply declare the member `std::tuple<component_manager<Ts>...> components;` and the constructor `ecs_manager() : components(std::make_tuple(component_manager<Ts>{}...)) {}`

Comment: How do you use `components` vector in `component_manager`? Where is `id_counter` defined? What line do you get the error at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure... but I suppose you're looking for

```
template <typename ... Ts>
class ecs_manager
 {
   public:
      std::tuple<component_manager<Ts>...> components;
    
      ecs_manager () 
          : components{ component_manager<Ts>{} ... }
       { }
 };
```

Anyway... C++ is a strongly typed language.

So you can't define an empty tuple

```
std::tuple<> components;
```

and recursively increment it

```
components = std::tuple_cat(components, component_manager<T>());
```

You have to define `components` as you want and you can't change it's type run-time

Comment: Thank you! I definitely need to look more into parameter packs haha